# JQuery: event listener removed after display:none?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a button with a "click" event listener defined on it with jQuery `bind()`. The event listener works fine until I (programmatically) do a `display:none` on the parent element (effectively hiding the parent element and the button). When I un-hide the parent element (`display:block`) the button doesn't work any more.

Example: let's say I have the following HTML markup with the following event listener:

```
$( ".my-button" ).bind( "click", myFunction );

<div class="container">
  <div class="my-button">Button</div>
</div>
```

If I, with another jQuery function, do a

```
$(".container").css('display', 'none');
```

the event listener disappears. Is this behaviour expected? Do I need to re-bind the event listener after each `display:none`?

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem?

Comment: Any errors in the browser console?

Comment: check for event listener after unhide with 
    $._data('.my-button', 'events');

Comment: I can reproduce consistently and I don't have any error messages (using Chrome)

Comment: Please provide a fiddle or code sample. In theory the bind event should not disappear like that.

Comment: Have you tried switching `$( ".my-button" ).bind( "click", myFunction );` to `$( ".my-button" ).on( "click", myFunction );`? This might fix the binding issue.

Comment: Appears to work fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/j30mddp2/. Can you reproduce the issue in a fiddle?

Comment: I'm sorry, it's my bad, I didn't realise that I actually removed the button from the DOM and re-added it. I'm sorry for wasting your time, my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/gadL2rag/

```
$(".container").css('display', 'none');
```

will not unbind the event, it will hide the .container div and its children. but after you call $(".container").css('display', 'block'); 
again, the event is still there, you don't have to bind it again. hope this help